# Checking whether a converter has already been registered

Tags: converters, boost-python

I have several modules which define converters for some trivial types (such as list of ints as `std::vector<int>`); they are parts of independent modules, but they are sometimes both used in one script, which leads to

```
RuntimeWarning: to-Python converter for std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > already registered; second conversion method ignored.
```

How can I check that converter for some type is already define and skip the second registration?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
boost::python::type_info info = boost::python::type_id<YourType>(); 
const boost::python::converter::registration* reg = boost::python::converter::registry::query(info); 
if (reg == NULL)  {
  //register YourType 
} else if ((*reg).m_to_python == NULL) {
  //register YourType 
}
```

Note that you need to check also for `((*reg).m_to_python == NULL)` otherwise you risk, in some architectures, that the registration does not happen as a default constructor because registration has been called assigning a NULL converter to YourType. In this case query(info) does return the address of the empty registration.

Answer (score 7):

You can probably query the registry, so something like this (untested)..

```
#include <boost/python/converter/registry.hpp>

boost::python::type_info info = boost::python::type_id<YourType>();
boost::python::converter::registration* reg = boost::python::converter::registry::query(info);
if (reg == NULL)
{
  //registry YourType
}
```